# How to write sql clause where column not equal and any id associated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to setup a simple query that will filter out any row that contains "A" in the ItemID, but my issue is I also do NOT want to display any journal ID from a different row since it matched "A". I tried googling the solution, but I am sure I am not using the right keywords to find it. I am using microsoft sql 2008, but I am not a database admin so I am not to familiar. I tried using distinct, and I also tried group by, but in this situation it does not work.

This is a simplified version of the table that I am working with:

```
JournalID    ItemID    PrimaryKEY
    1           A           1
    1           B           2
    2           A           3
    2           C           4
    3           B           5
    4           D           6
```

And here is how I would like to make it look:

```
JournalID    ItemID    PrimaryKEY
    3           B           5
    4           D           6
```

Comment: I apologize I didn't realize the snippets have to be manually ran I thought they would load automatically I will remake the table as plain text if preferred.

Comment: Posting your current query would also help in case there are any misunderstandings for what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will exclude any rows where the `ItemID` is 'A' and also any rows that have the same `JournalID` as a row where a `ItemID` was 'A'.

```
SELECT JournalID, ItemID, PrimaryKEY
FROM TABLE
WHERE JournalID NOT IN (Select JournalID FROM TABLE WHERE ItemID = 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE JournalID 
NOT IN (SELECT JournalID
FROM table_name
WHERE ItemID = 'A')
```